# Renders my safe_value instead of the value

Tags: entities

When I'm displaying the contentfield of a node, Drupal only shows the safe_value. I want to use the full HTML from my WYSIWYG. I know this because, when I change `$items[$id][$delta]['safe_value']` into $`items[$id][$delta]['value']` (in modules/field/modules/text/text.module line 159 in the text_field_load hook implementation), it displays the correct HTML from my WYSIWYG.

How can I change this, so that Drupal shows the value with the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change the filter of the field. That fixed the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? If you remember after more than a year, that is.